# User defined function for String?

Tags: java, string, user-defined-functions

I have following code in Java:

```
 public class StringSearch
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    String s = new String("I love my school. I love to play basketball. It is lovely weather. Love is life.");
    System.out.println(s);
    int i = -1;
    int count = 0;
    System.out.print("Counting love:");
    do{
      i = s.findW("love");
      if(i != -1){
        count++;
        System.out.print(count+" ");
      }
    }while(i != -1);
    System.out.println("The word \"love\" appears "+count+" times.");
  } 
}
```

I know that s.findW() is incorrect because findW() is not defined for Class String. However, is it possible to add user defined function in the class String and fix this?

Any alternative to fix this?

Hint for this problem is to read JDK documentation and fix the code. :/

Comment: "is it possible to add user defined function in the class String" `String` class is `final` as stated in documentation. You can add this method to other type, or use other methods like `contains` or `indexOf` (also mentioned in documentation)

Comment: _"Hint for this problem is to read JDK documentation and fix the code."_ So is this a quiz?

Comment: Create your own `findW(String string)` method and use it? What is this?

Comment: See String.indexOf...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would the use the indexOf method as follows:

```
    String s = new String("I love my school. I love to play basketball. It is lovely weather. Love is life.").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(s);
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    System.out.print("Counting love:");
    while(i != -1)
    {
      i = s.indexOf("love");
      if(i != -1){
        count++;
        s = s.substring(i+1);
        System.out.print(count+" ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The word \"love\" appears "+count+" times.");
```

Depending on whether you expect the answer to be 3 or 4, you would need to have the toLowerCase in there so that Love either matches or does not match.

Comment: Thanks! It is really embarrassing that I did not realize String class is final. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One quick question. Using this, program identifies 'Lovely' also as a found string. How can I exclude this?

Comment: Get rid of the toLowerCase() when creating the new string.  I wasn't sure if you wanted to include Lovely or not.

Comment: umm.. I meant even 'lovely' or say, 'truelove' would be identified as found. One more example - 'loveman' or 'like-love'. Sorry for bugging you again.

Comment: If you're saying that you only want the full word love then do the following: String[] str = s.split[" "];  for(int i = 0; i<str.length; i++){  if(str[i].equalsIgnoreCase("love")) count++; }

Answer (score 0):

The Java String class is final and cannot be altered. You could write your own but that would be crazy. There is generally enough funtionality on String already. If it doesn't do what you want, write a helper class with some methods.

Answer (score 0):

Java regex is your friend!

```
String s = "I love my school. I love to play basketball. It is lovely weather. Love is life.".toLowerCase();
     int count = (s.length() - s.replaceAll("love", "").length()) / 4;
     System.out.println("The word \"love\" appears " + count + " times.");
```